# View GWT HTML source?

Tags: java, html, gwt

Is there a way to VIEW the HTML source code that GWT produces? Currently I just give my flex table the DIV id and that DIV is all HTML I can see in ViewSource.

Is there a way to structure my table in HTML (say using div's and lists) and than create a something like FlexTable around that?

Comment: This is almost certainly not the best place for this, but would you recommend the GWT? & have you customised it with your own styles etc.?

Comment: Heh my friend! I am just starting digging around in it. I am a Django/python/prototype developer but Javascript is really getting to me. Just fiddling with GWT for now. See my other answer here comparing GWT to regular hosting: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/722463/is-google-app-engine-better-than-webfaction-for-a-beginner-in-django-dev/1732851#1732851

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To answer the original question, you can view the HTML GWT has rendered via 'Inspect Element' in Firefox, with Firebug is installed. Alternatively the Web Inspector in Safari/Chrome will do the trick, as will the Developer tools in both IE8 and Opera.

Comment: Thanks, Inspect element is what I was looking for!

Answer (score 0):

Well well it seems the answer is in the documentation.
In particular [Organizing Projects](http://code.google.com/webtoolkit/doc/1.6/DevGuideOrganizingProjects.html) outlines how we can bind different widgets to different id's on the page.
So I can effectively do something like:

```
# html
<div id="id_table"></div>
<div id="id_next_button"></div>

# java
t = new FlexTable()
RootPanel.get("id_table").add(t);
nextbtn = new Button("next");
RootPanel.get("id_next_button").add(nextbtn);
```

Wohoo!

Comment: Take a look at UIBinder too (http://code.google.com/p/google-web-toolkit/wiki/UiBinder) - it's even more amazing ;)

Answer (score 0):

Regarding the second part of your quetion. It is possible to create a HTML component in GWT. The recomended way to do this is extending **ComplexPanel** and create the elements using **Document.get().createXXXElement()**. But it is a little laborius.

Check out **[this dicussion](http://groups.google.com/group/Google-Web-Toolkit/browse_thread/thread/9d73b6cac18652bd?pli=1)** and I am sure there are other articles about this around the internet. You can also study the code of other components the extend ComplexPanel.